# Parsing through results in Wordpress Sql Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am fairly new and I am struggling with a simple Wordpress SQL query on the standard database for a plugin I am developing.

I am using the following code to echo out the titles of the first 10 posts:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts LIMIT 0, 10;"));

$i = 0;
while($i < count($results)){
    echo $results->post_title;
    $i++;
}
```

But nothing is getting echo'd out to the screen. There are a more that 10 posts in the database so not having data is not the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach ($results as $result) echo $result->post_title`? Cus I believe the code you have now would always echo the same thing. Also, turn on error reporting.

Comment: That worked, I tried with the foreach but couldn't really get my head around it thank you. If you post this as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe instead of this:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($results)){
    echo $results->post_title;
    $i++;
}
```

(Which will always echo the same variable), what you need to do is this:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->post_title;
}
```

Because `$results` is an array.

You might be able to do this as well, but there's no benefit over `foreach`:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($results)){
    echo $results[$i]->post_title;
    $i++;
}
```